# Rails set dynamic method value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I get an error trying to set a User model value using send. What is the correct method to use?

> SyntaxError ((irb):22: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting
>   end-of-input)

```
User.first.send(:first_name)="John"
```

Comment: `.send(:firstname, "john")`. but this is probably not what you want

Answer (score 4):

Use `public_send` when you want to dynamically infer a method name and call it, yet still don't want to have encapsulation issues.

```
user = User.first
user.public_send(:first_name=, 'Ray')
```

Perhaps `send` will also work in above code but not recommended in most of cases.

`User.first.public_send(:first_name=, 'Ray')` will be useless as you are assigning value to `User` object and this setter method do not save value.
Your object is not stored in any reference so you will lost object on which you have performed `setter` operation for `first_name`.

Take it in variable like *user* & then do such operations so you will have track, so later you can save *user* object and also you can view what changes you made for that variable

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a much easier method.

User.first[:first_name] = "John"